# Getting Numerics from end of a String in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I get numeric from end of a string
For example if string is `24Text147` i should get `147` only or if string is `text12` i should get `12` only.
Here is what I have found but it gives all the numerics in a string

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String

    Dim retval As String    
    Dim i As Integer        

    retval = ""
                                     '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If mId(s, i, 1) >= "0" And mId(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + mId(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
                             '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    Dim retval As String
    Dim i As Integer

    retval = ""
                                     '
    For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(s, i, 1) Like "#" Then
            retval = Mid(s, i, 1) & retval
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Comment: or just `if isnumeric (mid(s,i,1)) then`. +1 anyway, i like the `like`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Right(s, i)) Then
    onlyDigits = Right(s, i)
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next
End Function
```